# Background image which ignore container's bootstrap in the middle of a page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to put a background image in the middle of a page like this below.

[image]

A way would be to close the `div` container and put it back after my image. But I don't think that's the best way, so here I come to find some help.

My HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="job">
        <h4>Disc Jockey</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum...
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And in my css :

```
.job{
  margin-top: 75px;
  background:url(../img/bg-about.jpg) no-repeat center top scroll;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 357px;
  width: 1920px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a background image combined with an background color using rgba (for opacity) on the `<div class="job">` part. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. First time in stack overflow. The problem of my background is that it doesnt take full size of the screen because of the bootstrap' container

Comment: What do you mean ? my website is local for now.

Comment: Ok nvm, thanks for trying

Comment: Maybe you can you use [jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron). A working example can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add class .job to `<div class='container job'></div>` I think it must help you

Comment: My div.container is in the begining of my .html so i can't do that. I put it here to illustrate my issue.